# Ruby on Rails security. Disable printing or copying text.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Hello I'm trying to write a ruby on rails application, as part of the security requirements, i would like to disable the ability to print pages, and not allow text to be copied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of solution i've seen is to make a text with an image (it is possible with `gem rmagick`)

Comment: Thank you for this.. The problem is I have active buttons. Your image idea might fly if I use a transparent image layer.. I'II look into it. Cheers